# ASP.NET Core Options pattern with name split by single underscore

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-configuration

I am trying to load my app settings with ASP.NET Core Options pattern.

The `appsettings.json` contains:

```
{
  "TEst": "hello",
  "TEST_ABC": "2" 
}
```

POCO class:

```
public class AppSetting
{
    public string Test { get; set; }

    public string TestAbc { get; set; }
}
```

Bind to configuration:

```
services.Configure<AppSetting>(Configuration);
```

While access AppSetting instance in controller, I can only get config `Test` as `hello`. `TestAbc` is set to `null`.

It seems Options pattern couldn't convert this kind of naming configuration, is it possible by any other means to achieve this?

Comment: You try changing the Property to `Test_Abc`?

Comment: `TestAbc ` and `TEST_ABC` Are two different names, they have to match

Comment: @RyanWilson well, I am trying to not do that workaround, as it's not appropriate naming for property in C#.

Comment: @Train Yes, just looking for any solution allow that mismatch :)

Comment: You would need to tell the framework how to deal with the underscore, you could probably used `[JsonProperty("TEST_ABC")]` attribute for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way to have it done automatically would be to name your property with the underscore (`Test_Abc`). Short of that, you can specify the mapping manually:

```
services.Configure<AppSettings>(o => 
{
    o.TestAbc = Configuration["TEST_ABC"];
    // etc.
});
```

@DavidG's comment about using `[JsonProperty]` *may* work. I've never tried that in the context of configuration. However, it will only work, if it works at all, when using the JSON config provider. If you later need to satisfy this via an environment variable, for example, you're out of luck. As such, I would stick with a more universally applicable solution than that.

Answer (score 7):

Starting with .NET 6.0 Preview 7 you can use `ConfigurationKeyNameAttribute` class.

```cs
[ConfigurationKeyName("TEST_ABC")]
public string TestAbc { get; set; }
```