# How to bind appsettings.json setting with dots in the setting name

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, appsettings

After watching/reading some tutorials about the option pattern in .net for binding your settings to a c# model, I had this particular question about binding the setting “Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime” to a model.

[image]

**Situation**
I know how to bind settings to a model via the option pattern.
So having the appsettings.json file like

```
"FeatureFlags": {
    "IsFeature1Enabled": "false",
    "IsFeature2Enabled": "false",
    "IsFeature3Enabled": "true"
  }
```

would result in code like:

*model:*

```
public class FeatureFlagOptions
{
    public bool IsFeature1Enabled { get; set; } = false;
    public bool IsFeature2Enabled { get; set; } = false;
    public bool IsFeature3Enabled { get; set; } = false;
}
```

*startup.cs:*

```
private void SetUpAppSettingsModels(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<FeatureFlagOptions>(options => Configuration.GetSection("FeatureFlags").Bind(options));
}
```

*class with DI:*

```
private readonly FeatureFlagOptions _featureFlags;
public ClassNameHere(IOptions<FeatureFlagOptions> featureFlags)
{
    _featureFlags = featureFlags.Value;
}
```

**Question**

If you start a new web application and choose for example a web api, the standard appsettings will contain the appsetting “Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime”. Like in the picture in the beginning.
So how should I implement that setting in my model?

I Googled a lot, searched on stackoverflow and even my favorite blog writer Rick Strahl (https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/dec/12/easy-configuration-binding-in-aspnet-core-revisited) skipped the part with the logging section. I hope someone can help me with this one. Thanks!

Why do I want that property?: because reasons ;)

Comment: Based on this answer it would seem you'll need to specify the mapping directly, or possibly use an json name attribute specific to your json serialization library ie [JsonProperty] if using newtonsoft: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57774623/426894

Comment: Thanks for your input. Unfortunately, it resulted in a value of null instead of "information". The value of Default is not null and does contain the correct value "information". My model looked like:
public class LoggingModel
    {
        public LogLevel LogLevel { get; set; }
    }

    public class LogLevel
    {
        public string Default { get; set; }
        public string Microsoft { get; set; }

        //[JsonPropertyName("Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime")]
        [JsonProperty("Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime")]
        public string MicrosoftHostingLifetime {get; set; }
    }

Comment: Did you try it with the options configuration delegate like the code in the answer? Seems like that would work as you can specify the value via the string key name and assign it to whatever property you want. More details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-3.1#use-di-services-to-configure-options

Comment: Thanks @asawyer, the link was very informative, but it did not contain the solution. My final startup.cs contains now the following line: services.Configure<LoggingModel>(o =>{o.LogLevel = new LogLevel{
                    Default = Configuration["Default"],
                    Microsoft = Configuration["Microsoft"],
                    MicrosoftHostingLifetime = Configuration["Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime"]
                }; }); Instead of Default containing a value and the MicrosoftHostingLifetime being null, now both values are null. Besides, I want to prevent using Configuration['key'].

Comment: I'm not sure what to do if the Json property attributes aren't working and you don't want to use the configuration option delegate approach. By the way in your comment it looks like you have the key names incorrect. I think it should be `Configuration["Logging:LogLevel:Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime"]`

Comment: oh wow. That was very stupid of me. No idea what I was thinking. It worked with the code from my previous command and the correction of asawyer. o.LogLevel = new LogLevel{ MicrosoftHostingLifetime = Configuration["Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime"], ... }; will do the trick. Thanks @asawyer!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Asawyer, we came to a solution. Maybe there is a better one, but for now we fixed it as follows:

Model:

```
public class LoggingModel
{
    public LogLevel LogLevel { get; set; }
}

public class LogLevel
{
    public string Default { get; set; }
    public string Microsoft { get; set; }

    //[JsonProperty("Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime")] => Did not work :(
    public string MicrosoftHostingLifetime { get; set; }
}
```

*startup.cs:*

```
services.Configure<LoggingModel>(options => Configuration.GetSection("Logging").Bind(options));
services.Configure<LoggingModel>(options =>
{
     options.LogLevel.MicrosoftHostingLifetime = Configuration["Logging:LogLevel:Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime"];
});
```

*class with DI:*

```
private readonly LoggingModel _loggingModel;
public ClassNameHere(IOptions<LoggingModel> loggingOptions)
{
    _loggingModel= loggingOptions.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In .NET 6, the [ConfigurationKeyNameAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationkeynameattribute?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) has been added to support this

Answer (score -1):

In a similar situation, I used a less strongly typed solution, as the idea to read the specific settings in Startup.cs did not feel like a clean solution.

Here's my appsettings.json:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

And to read the "Logging.LogLevel" section I used a Dictionary instead

```
public class Logging
{
    public const string Default = "Default";
    public const string Microsoft = "Microsoft";
    public const string Microsoft_Hosting_Lifetime = "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime";

    public Dictionary<string, string> LogLevel { get; set; }
}
```

and to use this dictionary<string, string> while pretending that it's keys are not free style strings

```
var logLevels = loggingOptions.Value.LogLevel;
var logLevels_Default = logLevels[Logging.Default];
var logLevels_Microsoft = logLevels[Logging.Microsoft];
var logLevels_Microsoft_Hosting_Lifetime = logLevels[Logging.Microsoft_Hosting_Lifetime];
```