# Map appSettings.json object to class with different Json property names

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I am trying to map a JSON object in `settings.json` to a concrete class that has JSON Property Name matching the JSON object in settings.

```
public class GoogleServiceAccount
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("project_id")]
        public string ProjectId { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("private_key_id")]
        public string PrivateKeyId { get; set; }
    }
```

appSettings.json

```
"GoogleServiceAccount": {
    "type": "service_account",
    "project_id": "xxxxxx-xxxx",
    "private_key_id": "xxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

Program.cs

```
builder.Services.Configure<GoogleServiceAccount>(configuration.GetSection("GoogleServiceAccount"));
```

EmailService.cs

```
    public class EmailService
    {
        private readonly GoogleServiceAccount _gmailCredentials;
        public EmailService(IOptions<GoogleServiceAccount> credentials)
        {
            _gmailCredentials = credentials.Value;
        }
    }
```

Issue: I am getting null values in `EmailService` class for `GoogleServiceAccount`

**Solution:**
Since I am using .NET 6, `ConfigurationKeyName` instead of `JsonPropertyName` worked.

```
public class GoogleServiceAccount
        {
            [ConfigurationKeyName("type")]
            public string Type { get; set; }
    
            [ConfigurationKeyName("project_id")]
            public string ProjectId { get; set; }
    
            [ConfigurationKeyName("private_key_id")]
            public string PrivateKeyId { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: what's the issue you are facing?

Comment: Just edited the question. I am getting null values for GoogleServiceAccount.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45856136/customize-json-property-name-for-options-in-asp-net-core

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57773515/asp-net-core-options-pattern-with-name-split-by-single-underscore

Answer (score 0):

Configure like this code in your `Program.cs`:

```
builder.Services.Configure<GoogleServiceAccount>(o=> {
    o.Type = builder.Configuration["GoogleServiceAccount:type"];
    o.ProjectId = builder.Configuration["GoogleServiceAccount:project_id"];
    o.PrivateKeyId = builder.Configuration["GoogleServiceAccount:private_key_id"];

});
```

**Demo**

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is a good solution if you are not using .NET 6. `ConfigurationKeyName` in .NET 6 seems to be a much cleaner solution.

Comment: oh, It seems the new feature in .Net6.